# Why is it required to pass the values to the Tuple constructor?

Tags: c#, tuples

Why this is possible
`var x = new Tuple<int, int, int, string, string, string>(1, 1, 2, "dot", "net", "perls");`
but this isn't: 
`var x2 = new Tuple<List<int>, int, int, string, string, string>();`

I needed one of the elements to be a list of int.

Error I get is:

> Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required >formal parameter 'item1' of 'Tuple, int, int, string, string, >string>.Tuple(List, int, int, string, string, string)'

Comment: You have to pass the items to the constructor, as you did in the first example. Just as the error message says.

Answer (score 2):

Because as the message says you didn't give any List for the first argument (actually you didn't give the others as well).

```
List<int> thisIsAList = new List<int>{1,2,3};
var x = new Tuple<List<int>, int, int, string, string, string>(thisIsAList, 1, 2, "dot", "net", "perls");
```

Answer (score 0):

The second tuple declaration *is also valid*.

What's actually *invalid* is the fact that the tuple has 6 parameters but you're not passing in any arguments to the constructor.

The solution is to supply the necessary arguments as you've done in your first example.